# Get counts in grid cell for multiple values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, count, multi-values

I have 500+ polygon shapefiles with nationwide coverage.  Each shapefile has possible record values of 0-4.  I want to get the value that intersects each grid centroid and then get a total count for all the shapefiles.

[image: Grid Overlay Polygon Shapefile]

So my final output will be a 1 km grid with value fields 0,1,2,3,4 and counts for each value like below.

[image: Output Table]

I'm limited to ArcGIS for software.

I know I can do this by leaving everything in vector form and creating a fishnet with label points, doing spatial joins and summary statistics, but its a bit unwieldy.  I'm not as familiar with the raster tools available with ArcGIS and can't find anything that fits my needs.  If I convert all the 500+ shapefiles to raster is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: These shapefiles, are they points with a value of 0,1,2,3 or 4? May be an image of what you are talking about will help?

Comment: Images added to post.

Comment: Although you request a "sum," your example describes counts.  Which one do you want?

Comment: I want the count of how many times the value (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) is at the center of the grid cell so I can then get a frequency for each value by calculating Count / Total Number of Shapefiles.

Comment: What's the significance of the green and blue polygon and what do those labels 1 and 0 mean?

Comment: The green/blue polygons are one of the shapefiles that I want my grid cell centroids to intersect.  In this example Green is 1 and Blue is 2.  So all the grid cells that have their centroid intersect a 0 (Blue) would get 0, all the grid cells that have their centroid intersect a 1 (Green) would get 1.  I would do this same operation to each of the 500+ shapefiles.  Then in the end I want a result like my example table, where I can see how many times a certain grid cell centroid was intersected each value.

Comment: so, you want to know how many of your 1KM gridded polygons have a 'record' value of 0-4? For instance, you want to be able to calculate if 30% of the entire grid has a value of "2"? Or that only 1% of the gridded polygons have a value of "4"? So, if I understand correctly, you have two datasets, at different resolutions. One is a 1KM grid of polygons, and one is an irregular dataset of some type, which does not match the resolution of the previous one. You wish to lay the project data onto the grid you have created, and assign a value to each grid cell, and then subsequently count how many cel

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  I note that you have not yet taken our 2-minute [Tour] that introduces users to the site and its protocols.